# Why does child process ignore exit(0) AND ignore the sleep function?

Tags: c, linux, process, signals

I send to the child a sigusr2 with a handler that exits  however it doesn't stop even after receiving that signal ignoring it and ignoring the sleep function also (i put the sleep function just to test if process is killed)
Here is my code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

void this(int sig)
{
    write(STDOUT_FILENO,"Yep\n",13);
}

void fuckingdie(int sig)
{
    exit(0);
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGUSR1, this);
    signal(SIGUSR2, fuckingdie);
    pid_t pid = fork();
    pid_t pid2;
    if (pid < 0) {
        exit(-1);
    }
    else if (pid == 0) {
        pause();
        sleep(100);
        printf("error\n");
    }
    else {
        pid2 = fork();
        if (pid2 < 0) {
            exit(-2);
        }
        else if (pid2 == 0) {
            pause();
            kill(pid, SIGUSR2);
            printf("signal sent to first child\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("this is the parent\n");
            kill(pid2, SIGUSR1);
            printf("signal sent to second child\n");
            wait(NULL);
            printf("waiting for second child\n");
            wait(NULL);
            printf("waited for both");
            exit(-3);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: `write(STDOUT_FILENO,"Yep\n",13)` Well, that can't be good.  Yep\n is only 4 chars.

Comment: I would speculate that the USR1 signal arrives in the second child before it calls `pause`.

Comment: The code presented in this question has substantially the same structure as that in your previous question.  You've fixed some of the minor details, but the main problem is the same.

Comment: For extra clarity: `pause()` is the wrong tool for the second child's job.  There is no way to make it the right tool.  See Glibc's discussion of [waiting for a signal](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Waiting-for-a-Signal.html) for more information, especially the part about problems with `pause()`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger sorry thought after fixing the mistakes this was different but i guess my bad

Comment: @WilliamPursell but that doesn't correlate with the problem i'm having right?

Comment: The incorrect count to `write` is probably not practically a problem, but the signal arriving before the child calls pause is exactly the problem you are having.  The signal arrives, the child handles it, then it pauses forever.  This is a classic race condition.  Check the documentation for `sigsuspend` and read the documentation John Bollinger gave the link for.